# Yacc fails with one declaration but reduce two declarations with success

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc

I have the following yacc parser (don't have any conflict) for int or float variable declaration:

```
%token ID INT FLOAT
%token SEMICOLON

%%

program                : list_declaration { printf("program\n"); }
                       ;

list_declaration       : declaration { printf("list_declaration\n"); } 
                       | declaration declaration { printf("list_declaration\n"); }
                       ;

declaration            : var_declaration { printf("declaration\n"); }
                       ;

var_declaration        : type ID SEMICOLON { printf("var_declaration\n"); }
                       ;

type                   : INT { printf("type\n"); }
                       | FLOAT { printf("type\n"); }
                       ;

%%
```

I've been knocking my head trying to solve this problem but didn't come with any solutions.
If there's two variable declarations as input, like:

```
 int test;
 float test2;
```

Its parsed normally, here is the output:

```
 type
 var_declaration
 declaration
 type
 var_declaration
 declaration
 list_declaration
 program
```

But if there's only one declaration the parser never reduces it to program, for instance:

```
 int test;
```

gives:

```
 type
 var_declaration
 declaration
```

Shouldn't declaration be reduced to list_declaration and then list_declaration reduced to program? I'm planning later to extend list_declaration to any number of declarations, but I can't do that unless I understand first why is not working properly for at least two declarations.

Comment: Does your scanner try to intercept `EOF`? Or does it just leave flex free to do the right thing?

Comment: @rici My scanner captures eof, since i'm using a pointer to a file as yyin, I have " do { yyparse(); } while (!feof(yyin)); "

Comment: No, you don't. And if you did, capturing EOF in the scanner would be wrong; you should be using `yywrap` for that.

Comment: Your `list_declaration` production only allows one or two declarations. It should be `list_declaration : declaration { ... } | list_declaration declaration { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly that you are suppressing the `EOF` return from `yylex`. `yylex` *must* return 0 on EOF; otherwise, `bison` parsers cannot reliably recognize the start production.

Like most parser generators -- and as described in most parsing textbooks -- bison and yacc create an "augmented" start production whose right-hand side consists of the declared (or implicit) start non-terminal followed by an `EOF` pseudo-token. The parse will only succeed if that production is reduced, and that production cannot be reduced without the `EOF`.

Because `bison` will reduce without lookahead for states in which lookahead is unnecessary, it is possible, with your grammar, for `bison` to reduce `declaration declaration` to `program` without lookahead. But it cannot reduce `declaration` to `program` without the `EOF` lookahead, so it doesn't. In the case with two `declarations`, despite the fact that `program` has been reduced, the parse has not actually succeeded and `yyparse` will not have returned.

Comment: Thanks @rici, it was exactly that, using yywrap() the problem was solved.